# How to automate user Input on prompt Python script in shell

Tags: python, shell, vagrant, pgadmin-4

I'm writing automating of installation `pgAdmin4` on CentOS7 with `Vagrant`.
At one stage python setup script prompts to enter email address and then password:

```
$ python /usr/lib/pgadmin4/setup.py
Enter the email address and password to use for the initial pgAdmin user account:

Email address:
```

I'd like to use linux shell to automate input, but different ways don't work for me.
Something like that:

```bash
python /usr/lib/pgadmin4/setup.py <<EOF
> mail@domain.com
> password
> EOF
Enter the email address and password to use for the initial pgAdmin user account:

Email address: Password:
```

If there way to automate input when python script will run?

Comment: why not just modify the setup.py script to remove console inputs with hard coded variables ?

Comment: "something like that" -- what happens when you do ___exactly___ that?

Comment: Some programs (like ssh) do something like flushing stdin so that you cannot pipe the password in. Does this python program do something similar?